# Unable to connect Web App on Azure to remote database

Tags: mysql, node.js, azure-web-app-service

I deployed a `next js` web application on to `Azure Web App Service`, and want to use it to connect to existing remote database, however I am keep getting such error in the log stream:

```
2021-04-23T18:09:17.315942065Z Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
2021-04-23T18:09:17.315993564Z     at Query._callback (/home/site/wwwroot/.next/server/pages/api/getFromUrl.js:128:16)
2021-04-23T18:09:17.316000664Z     at Query.Sequence.end (/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:83:24)
2021-04-23T18:09:17.316013164Z     at /node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:205:13
2021-04-23T18:09:17.316017064Z     at Handshake.onConnect (/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:58:9)
2021-04-23T18:09:17.316020764Z     at Handshake.<anonymous> (/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:526:10)
2021-04-23T18:09:17.316025064Z     at Handshake._callback (/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:488:16)
2021-04-23T18:09:17.316028764Z     at Handshake.Sequence.end (/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:83:24)
2021-04-23T18:09:17.316032364Z     at Protocol.handleNetworkError (/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:369:14)
2021-04-23T18:09:17.316035964Z     at PoolConnection.Connection._handleNetworkError (/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:418:18)
2021-04-23T18:09:17.316039564Z     at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
```

My db connection in the app is:

```
export const db = mysql.createPool({
    host: 'abcd.efghosting.com',
    port: 3306,
    database: 'pwpush',
    user: 'pwpush_user',
    password: ....,
    multipleStatements: true,
});
```

Not sure why it's trying to connect to `127.0.0.1:3306`

I tried to open something like hybrid-connection to the database endpoint but that didn't work.

Comment: You may be using your local `dbconfig.dev.js` file instead of `db.config.prod.js` file, please confirm again.

Comment: Has your problem been solved? Is there any progress?

Comment: Sorry I am still not able to solve it. I don't have any db.config.prod.js file under the root repo

Comment: Pls show the structure of your project.

Answer (score 0):

## Troubleshooting

1. Check which `db.js` you use.
2. Use hybrid-connection correctly.

> Create a new Hybrid Connection and set the Endpoint Host name with the actual name/IP address, where the Hybrid Connection Manager is installed.

For more details, please refer Tassisto's answer.

[Web API hosted on Azure doesn't return On-Premise Data after Get Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67131197/web-api-hosted-on-azure-doesnt-return-on-premise-data-after-get-request/67155728#67155728)